# Different operations with different datasets in a function

Tags: r

I need to come up with a function that base on different datasets that were fed into the function, the operations are different. Using `mtcars` and `iris` as an example:

```
func<-function(df) {
  if (df ==mtcars){
  df%>%summarise(cnt=n())}
  else{
    df
  }
}
func(mtcars)
func(iris)
```

If it's `mtcars`, give me the count of it, but if it's `iris` just give back how it is to me. However, this code does not work like the way I want it. When I do `func(mtcars)` I get warining message like this

`Warning message:
In if (df == mtcars) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. 
If I do `func(iris)`, it throw error at me
`Error in Ops.data.frame(df, mtcars) : 
  ‘==’ only defined for equally-sized data frames`.
So how do I fix it?

Comment: What kind of different things do you want to do to these objects. Is the behavior really determined by the name of the variable you pass in? What if you did `my_cars <- mtcars; func(my_cars)`? Is that the same as passing `mtcars` in? It might be a good idea to step back and say what exactly the design goals for this function are.

Comment: Adding to MrFlick's excellent point with a more pathological example, if I do `mtcars <- iris; func(mtcars)` what should happen?

Comment: @MrFlick @ Gregor --reinstate Monica-- Currently I have two datasets. When I feed in `df1`, what I want is to do something like `df1%>%group_by(groups)%>%summarise(cnt=n(),rate=col1/col2)`.When I feed in '`df2`,I just need anything above but `rate=col1/col2` bc due to the nature of `df2`, I can't and don't need to calculate any rate. I thought using the function in my original post as examples can simplify the question.

Comment: It just seems so weirdly specific... I think a more normal way to do it would be to have 2 functions, and only call `func1` on `df1` and `func2` on `df2`. If you need to figure out which one to call programmatically, think about what the *meaningful* difference---or at least a small easy-to-test difference (presence of a grouping column, number of rows or columns, etc.) rather than see if every value is identical.